# How pass dynamic arguments to the datetime.timedelta function?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I'm working on a python3 script where I use `timedelta()` function and need to pass parameters (keyword arguments with values) to [timedelta()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) dynamically.

I tried several things but I can't figure out how to do this.

```
from datetime import timedelta

timeDeltaArgKey = "minutes"
timeDeltaArgValue = 60


timedelta(timeDeltaArgKey=timeDeltaArgValue)
# TypeError: 'timeDeltaArgKey' is an invalid keyword argument for __new__()

timedelta("{}={}".format(timeDeltaArgKey, timeDeltaArgValue))
# TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: str
```

I also tried to pass it in as an array:

```
timeDeltaKwarg = {"minutes": 60}

timedelta(timeDeltaKwarg)
# TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: dict
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unpack the dictionary to pass it:

```
timeDeltaKwarg = {"minutes": 60}
timedelta(**timeDeltaKwarg)
```

Or you can simply pass it as normal parameter

```
timedelta(minutes=60)
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a keyword arguments dictionary and pass it to `timedelta`:

```
from datetime import timedelta


timeDeltaArg1Key = "days"
timeDeltaArg1Value = 3
timeDeltaArg2Key = "minutes"
timeDeltaArg2Value = 60

kwargs = {timeDeltaArg1Key: timeDeltaArg1Value, timeDeltaArg2Key: timeDeltaArg2Value}

result = timedelta(**kwargs)
print(result)  # -> 3 days, 1:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use timedelta as follows:

```
datetime.timedelta(days=0, seconds=0, microseconds=0, milliseconds=0, minutes=0, hours=0, weeks=0)
```

Comment: i need also to pass the key (minutes in my case) dynamically